# customizable option file(.pdf) is not open

Tags: custom, pdf, option

In product custom option type is File. I allow only png, jpeg, txt, pdf extension.

In place order time when I select PDF, it's work. A custom option also select.

But when we open that file (pub/media/custom_options/quote/n/e/jMvJIA50kksnMXL1gxcC0um5Hm0vL0HA) it displays error.

[image]

Comment: Give pub folder 777 permission and check.

Comment: no is not permission issue . 

it has no extension thats why it generate error i just rename with .pdf extension and it open

Comment: @HaFiz Umer Please check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I Think the
**Generated Document has no Proper File Extension**

So **Please try to add .pdf after file name**  `(in your case the file name should  jMvJIA50kksnMXL1gxcC0um5Hm0vL0HA.pdf)`  then open Document , Also check your code properly add the document extension for fix this issue permanently

> ex: your_filename.pdf

Hope this help you , Thanks